# How does this Hadith prove trustworthiness of Prophet (s)

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad

I am reading a book (Iman 100 by Teyba Foundation) and it says:

"It was also this trustworthiness that she [Khadija (r)] reminded him of when the revelation first came to him. When he came down from the mountain and was afraid of what occurred and that he feared it may not be something good, she told him in her beautiful words:

'Never! By God, God will never disgrace you. You keep good relations with your relatives, help the poor, serve your guests generously, and assist those hit with calamities.' (Sahih al-Bukhari)"

That is the exact quote form the book. What I am failing to see is where the hadith refers to the tustworthiness of the Prophet (s). It seems to refer to maintaining kinship bonds etc, but I am not seeing how these things imply trustworthiness. I thought trustworthiness was when you are entrusted things/responsibilities by people and you successfully take care of them and fulfill them.

Could it be that the author of the book I am reading meant that Prophet Muhammad (s) fulfilled the trusts and rights of people, and in *that* sense he was trustworthy (as well as the sense I just mentioned of literally taking care of things and tasks given to you by others).

tl;dr: In the above quote, what does the author mean by saying "It was also this trustworthiness that she [Khadija (r)] reminded him of", ie how does the hadith mentioned show his trustworthiness?

Comment: Your question is about a quote from a book and the potential intention of the author, but you neither mention the book nor the author. Please refer to [ask], and take a [tour] in our [help].

Comment: @III-AK-III: Is it correct now? Also I just wanted to mention that it is not about the intentions of the author, I just don't understand how this particular hadith is related to trustworthiness (as the author claims). If someone is able to see this then I would appreciate clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. People view someone as trustworthy when they fulfill the rights of people, as you said. But also, Khadijah (ra) seemed to have commented directly on his honesty *(and people usually view someone as trustworthy when they are honest)*. Peace and blessings be upon him.

Here's some different hadiths which report what Khadijah (ra) said:

> [Sahih Al Bukhari (4953)](https://sunnah.com/urn/46331): Khadija said, "Nay! But receive the good tidings! By Allah, Allah will never disgrace you, for by Allah, you keep good relations with your Kith and kin, **speak the truth**, help the poor and the destitute, entertain your guests generously and assist those who are stricken with calamities."

And

> [Sahih Muslim (160)](https://sunnah.com/muslim:160a): By Allah, you join ties of relationship, **you speak the truth**, you bear people's burden, you help the destitute, you entertain guests, and you help against the vicissitudes which affect people."

Hope that helps.

ALSO, if you are interested in reading different testimonies on truthfulness of the Prophet [and the level of trust people had in him] then see this compilation which I made from his family, friends, followers and even enemies!! (Link: [Truthfulness of the Prophet](https://veiledink.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/truthfulness-of-the-prophet-%EF%B7%BA/)).